# code igniter database error no 1064

Tags: codeigniter

A Database Error Occurred

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE 0 = 'junaid' LIMIT 1' at line 2

```
SELECT * WHERE 0 = 'junaid' LIMIT 1
```

> Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
>
> Line Number: 1134

when I enter data in the username and password fields, like username = junaid and pasword=12345.. and this record is present in users database having a login column.. please tell me how to get rid of this error

Comment: What is `0` supposed to mean here? Why not `SELECT * WHERE username = 'junaid' LIMIT 1`?

Comment: i dont know about this 0 matt..

Comment: You will need to read a good tutorial to archive this.. Your sql is wrong, you must use something like: `select * from tableName where useraname='junaid' and password = '1234..' ` and then check if exist that user, but you will need to store passwords in no plain text format and return the user if it is correct. If you are using CI, you should post the controller + modell php.

Comment: its too long for a comment..